# How to calculate northEast coordinate by radius and center on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math, 2d, coordinates

I have this formula:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();

var center = bounds.getCenter();
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();

// r = radius of the earth in statute miles
var r = 3963.0;  

// Convert lat or lng from decimal degrees into radians (divide by 57.2958)
var lat1 = center.lat() / 57.2958; 
var lon1 = center.lng() / 57.2958;
var lat2 = ne.lat() / 57.2958;
var lon2 = ne.lng() / 57.2958;

// distance = circle radius from center to Northeast corner of bounds
var dis = r * Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) + 
  Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lon2 - lon1));
```

It calculates radius by NE and center. 
I need: Formula to calculate NE coordinate by given radius and center on map written with js.

Comment: This is just the formula for calculating the distance of ( the angle between) two points given in polar coordinates. Multiplied by `r` its the arc length. So if you have the arc the angle is just `arc/r`, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, so it's wrong formula ? I have NorthEast coordinates and center coordinates. I have a map, and it has rectangular form.  NorthEast coordinates are placed right at my top-left corner of this map. I need to find radius of circle that is written inside my rectangle. And vise versa, formula to find NE coordinates by given radius and center. Please check my web-app. Try "find in this area" on map(this is where my firs formula is used), then change url and try again(second formula - has not created yet)
https://www.1000viewpoints.com/ (Click explore catalog)

Comment: No for the distance the formula is correct. It gives you the distance between two points on a sphere of which you know the polar coordinates. It requires the knowledge of the sphere's radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first I guess it will help to understand where the used formula comes from. 
**And even before that, note that I will use standard mathematical coordinates. This differs from geographical long/lat but should be easy to transform**

Hence a point on a sphere is `(x,y,z)= r*(cos p sin t, sin p sin t, cos t)`. So `p` is the angle from `x` to `y` and `t` is the angle of the `z`-axis.

If you have two points (p,t) and (q, u) we can rotate the first point to p=0, i.e. over the `x`-axis. Than the points have coordinates `(0,t)` and `(q-p,u)`. Now we rotate the points around `y` such that the first point becomes the north pole.

```
[ cos t, 0, -sin t]   [x]     [ cos t, 0, -sin t]   [ cos(q-p) sin(u)]
[    0   1,   0   ] . [y]  =  [    0   1,   0   ] . [ sin(q-p) sin(u)] 
[ sin t, 0,  cos t]   [z]     [ sin t, 0,  cos t]   [       cos(u)    ]
```

the new `z` than is

```
z_new = sin(t) cos(q-p) sin(u) + cos(t)cos(u)
```

Naturally the arc length from here to the north pole is just

```
alpha = arcsin( sin(t) cos(q-p) sin(u) + cos(t)cos(u) )
```

and for the true distance we have to multiply with the radius `r` of the sphere.

Now the other way. we have a point `(p,t)` and want the `(q,u)` given that its direction is an angle `beta` off north and in distance `d`. In a fist step we set point `(p,t)` as north pole. That makes the second point `(Pi + beta, d/r)` (Note angles are mathematical positive if ccw). This system has to be rotated such that the north pole goes to the given `(p,t)`. This is done by

```
[  cos t, sin t,  0]   [ cos p, 0,  sin p]   [x]   
[ -sin p, cos t,  0] . [    0   1,   0   ] . [y]  
[   0   ,  0   ,  1]   [ -sin p, 0, cos p]   [z]
```

setting `(Pi + beta, d/r) = (gamma, theta)` we get

```
z_new = -sin(p)cos(gamma)sin(theta)+cos(p)cos(theta)
```

consequently:

```
u = arccos( z_new )
```

Finally:

```
x_new = cos(t) ( cos(p)cos(gamma)sin(theta) + sin(p)cos(theta) ) + sin(theta)sin(gamma)sin(theta)
```

As `x_new = cos(q)sin(u)` and we know `u`

```
q = arccos( xnew / sin(u) ) = arccos( xnew / sqrt( 1 - z_new ) )
```

I hope I got it all right and remember this is in typical mathematical polar coordinates and **it has to be translated to the sin/cos usage and angle definition in geography**.